# No mapping exists from object type Models.ApplicationModel

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Im getting this error:

> No mapping exists from object type `Vue2Spa.Models.ApplicationModel`
>   to a known managed provider native type.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType,
>   object value, bool inferLen, bool streamAllowed)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetMetaTypeOnly()
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(int index, bool
>   isCommandProc)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, int
>   startCount, bool inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(bool inSchema,
>   SqlParameterCollection parameters, ref _SqlRPC rpc)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

My `AddApplication` function:

```
public int AddApplication(ApplicationModel item)
        {

        string SandBoxDB = configuration.GetConnectionString("SandBoxDB");
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SandBoxDB))

           item.Prefferedcampus);
```

My controller:

```
 public class ApplicationController : BaseController
{
    private ApplicationManager manager;
    public ApplicationController(IConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {
        manager = new ApplicationManager(config);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationModel> Index()
    {
        return manager.GetApplication();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public int Create([FromBody] ApplicationModel application)
    {
        return manager.AddApplication(application);
    }
```

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your "@PhoneNumber" parameter, you are mistakenly passing in the entire model instead of the property value. The line in question is this one:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", item);
```

Instead, it should be something like

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", item.PhoneNumber); 
// Or whatever the phone number property is.
```